# Will this function be measurable

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Let $f\in L^2(0,1)$ and $g\in L^2(0,1)$. Is any function that lies point-wise between $f$ and $g$ going to be Lebesgue measurable, i.e. $$f(x)\le h(x)\le g(x), \quad \forall x\in [0,1]$$
then is $h(x)$ Lebesgue measurable?

Comment: Is it really true that any bounded function measurable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's glaringly false. Pick $f=0$, $g=1$ and $h=\chi_{\text{Vitali set}}$.

Comment: Oh, you are right.